# chrome devtools -- emulated mobile device external background theme stuck in light mode

Tags: google-chrome, themes, preferences, google-developer-tools

[image]

chrome set to dark theme, devtools set to dark them, but I can't get the area surrounding the emulated device to match. the bright light theme hurts my eyes (and my soul). can anyone confirm if there is a setting for this?